# Explicitly statically typed programming langagues

Tags: oop, static-typing

I am curious.

I am interested in knowing if any languages exist like C++ and Java, in that the langauge is:
(a) Explicitly (ie. not by inference) statically typed, (b) Object Oriented.

I am aware of D, but what others are people using?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C, Eiffel, C#, AS3, Perl are some languages that springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

C# and Objective C come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

C# 10. and 2.0 are explicitly-typed.  Type inference was introduced in C# 3.0 with the `var` keyword.

Comment: var is inference though, iirc this means that
var x = 11;
x = "hello"; is invalid